# Swap items of a linked list in pairs - revision 4

Tags: java, unit-testing, linked-list, interview-questions

Here is [the source of the question.](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=6313112158339072)

The solution on [GitHub.](https://github.com/MaksimDmitriev/Reverse-LinkedList)

[Revision 1.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96871/23821)

[Revision 2.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/97874/23821)

[Revision 3.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/98120/23821)

[@200_success' suggestions from revision 3:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/98144/23821)

- The iterator's `next()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if we run off the last element of the list while iterating.
- `Iterator.remove()` is implemented.
- The implementation of `SinglyLinkedList.toString()` is more straightforward.

---

My changes:

- `toArray` and `size` for tests.
- I made `Node` a static nested class of `SinglyLinkedList` as they do with `Entry` in [the Java LinkedList class.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.Entry) It allowed me not to implement `setNext`, `getNext`, and `getData` of `Node`. Anyway, `Node` not accessible for client code. So I think I can access members of `Node` directly, and it's not dangerous.

The questions I have now:

1. Do my tests cover all the edge cases of the algorithm? See `SinglyLinkedList.reversePairs()` and `SinglyLinkedListTest`.
2. Do I need to null out the reference to `cur` in my `iterator`'s `remove()` method? See the uploaded image below the questions.
3. Why would I need `SinglyLinkedList.equals()` which was suggested [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/98144/23821)?

[image: My iterator's remove()]

**SinglyLinkedList**

```
package com.singlylinkedlist;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class SinglyLinkedList implements Iterable<Integer> {

    /** Dummy node */
    private final Node head = new Node(0);
    private int size;

    public SinglyLinkedList(int[] data) {
        for (int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            addFirst(data[i]);
        }
    }

    public void addFirst(int datum) {
        Node n = new Node(datum);
        n.next = head.next;
        head.next = n;
        size++;
    }

    public void reversePairs() {
        // For each loop iteration, transform
        //
        // maybe null --+
        // |
        // v
        // Original: (a) -> b -> c -> d ...
        // To: a -> c -> (b) -> d ...
        // ^
        // |
        // +-- becomes "a" of the next iteration

        Node a = this.head, b, c;
        while ((b = a.next) != null && (c = b.next) != null) {
            Node d = c.next;
            a.next = c;
            c.next = b;
            b.next = d;
            a = b;
        }
    }

    public int[] toArray() {
        int array[] = new int[size];
        int i = 0;
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            array[i++] = iterator.next();
        }
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = iterator();
        if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
            return "[]";
        }

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("[" + iterator.next());
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            int nodeValue = iterator.next();
            s.append(" -> " + nodeValue);
        }
        return s.append(']').toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {

            Node prev;
            Node current = head;
            Node next = current.next;

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                prev.next = next;
                current.next = null;
                current = null; // TODO: Do I need to eliminate this obsolete reference?
                current = next;
                if (current == null) {
                    next = null;
                } else {
                    next = current.next;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                prev = current;
                current = next;
                next = next.next;
                return current.data;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return next != null;
            }

        };
    }

    private static class Node {

         Node next;
         int data;

         Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof Node)) {
                return false;
            }
            Node another = (Node) obj;
            return data == another.data;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = 17;
            result = 31 * result + data;
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

**SinglyLinkedListTest**

```
package com.singlylinkedlist;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SinglyLinkedListTest {

    @Test
    public void testEmpty() {
        int[] orig = new int[] {};
        int[] reversed = new int[] {};
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(reversed, linkedList.toArray());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingle() {
        int[] orig = new int[] { 1 };
        int[] reversed = new int[] { 1 };
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(reversed, linkedList.toArray());
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoopOnce() {
        int[] orig = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        int[] reversed = new int[] { 2, 1 };
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(reversed, linkedList.toArray());

    }

    @Test
    public void testLoopMoreThanOnce() {
        int[] orig = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] reversed = new int[] { 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5 };
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(reversed, linkedList.toArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you are taking an improper shortcut with your box-and-pointer diagrams by labelling the boxes with variable names.  Such a shortcut will lead to errors in reasoning.  Here's how you should draw your first diagram instead:

$$
\newcommand{ptr}[1]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\longrightarrow}}
\begin{align}
& \mathtt{prev}         && \mathtt{cur}          && \mathtt{next} \\
& \downarrow            && \downarrow            && \downarrow \\
& \fbox{Node}\ptr{next} && \fbox{Node}\ptr{next} && \fbox{Node}\ptr{next} \cdots
\end{align}
$$

`prev`, `cur`, and `next` are variables that refer to instances of `Node`.  Each instance is an object that has no intrinsic name.

---

[`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) *must* throw an `IllegalStateOperation` if `next()` has not yet been called, or if `next()` has not been called between two calls to `remove()`.  In addition, you *may* choose to throw a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) if you detect contention.

I don't believe you need three `Node` variables in the iterator.  Here's how I would write it:

```
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Integer>() {
        Node prev = head, current = head;
        boolean removable = false;

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            if (!this.removable) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("next() has not been called");
            }
            this.removable = false;
            this.prev.next = this.current.next;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            if (this.removable) this.prev = this.current;
            this.current = this.current.next;
            this.removable = true;
            return this.current.data;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return this.current.next != null;
        }

    };
}
```

---

The `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of `Node` are never called in this code, nor is the `Node` ever revealed outside the class.  Therefore, these methods are dead code.

They could be implemented more simply:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj == this ||
           (obj instanceof Node && this.data == ((Node)obj).data);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.data;
}
```

I think that [there is no point](//stackoverflow.com/q/11890805/1157100) to adding 527 to every hashcode.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your `remove()`. It looks like you remove `prev` rather than `current`. However, it works as expected

Comment: I deleted `hashCode` and `equals()`. They aren't essential in my solution. But what do you mean by adding 527?

Comment: `31 * result` is always 527.

Comment: `this.prev.next = this.current.next` does the real work. `this.prev = null` doesn't delete `prev`; it just unsets `prev` such that you can't `remove()` again until you call `next()` first. (The difference between unsetting and deleting illustrates why you shouldn't label box-and-pointer diagrams the way you did.)

Comment: I got your idea about 527. In fact, I just copied the example from _Effective Java 2nd Edition_ (page 48).

Comment: I understood your `remove`. But don't you need to null out a reference `cur` holds? I.e., please prove me there is no memory leak in your solution.

Comment: After calling `remove()`, `this.current` holds a lingering reference to the deleted node. The deleted node would be eligible for garbage collection after the next call to `next()`.

Comment: There was a bug in Rev 2, fixed in Rev 3. I was being too clever, trying to use `prev = null` as a signal that `remove()` is not ready to be called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26590/discussion-between-maksim-dmitriev-and-200-success).