# Swap items of a linked list in pairs - revision 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, linked-list, interview-questions

Here is [the source of the question.](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=6313112158339072)

> Given a singly linked list, swap the list items in pairs (reconnect
>   the pointers, not simply swap the values). For example:
>
> Before: A->B->C->D
>
> After: B->A->D->C

- [Revision 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96871/23821)
- [Revision 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/97874/23821)
- [Revision 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/98120/23821)
- [Revision 4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/98810/23821)

This revision is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MaksimDmitriev/Reverse-LinkedList/tree/rev5).

I decided not to delete my `iterator` although it's not essential for pair-reversing items in a singly linked list. But with help of @200_success I have a good iterator, and I want to keep it.

In this revision I'd love to focus on code coverage. I use [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/index.html) for Eclipse to see which branches of code are covered.

**SinglyLinkedList**

```
package com.singlylinkedlist;

import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class SinglyLinkedList implements Iterable<Integer> {

    /** Dummy node */
    private final Node head = new Node(0);
    private int size;
    private int modCount = 0;

    public SinglyLinkedList(int... data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            addFirst(data[i]);
        }
    }

    public void addFirst(int datum) {
        Node n = new Node(datum);
        n.next = head.next;
        head.next = n;
        size++;
        modCount++;
    }

    public boolean reversePairs() {
        if (size < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        // For each loop iteration, transform
        //
        // maybe null --+
        // |
        // v
        // Original: (a) -> b -> c -> d ...
        // To: a -> c -> (b) -> d ...
        // ^
        // |
        // +-- becomes "a" of the next iteration

        Node a = this.head, b, c;
        while ((b = a.next) != null && (c = b.next) != null) {
            Node d = c.next;
            a.next = c;
            c.next = b;
            b.next = d;
            a = b;
        }
        modCount++;
        return true;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public int[] toArray() {
        int array[] = new int[size];
        int i = 0;
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            array[i++] = iterator.next();
        }
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = iterator();
        if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
            return "[]";
        }

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("[" + iterator.next());
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            int nodeValue = iterator.next();
            s.append(" -> " + nodeValue);
        }
        return s.append(']').toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
            Node prev = head, current = head;
            boolean removable = false;
            int expectedModCount = modCount;

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                if (!this.removable) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("next() has not been called");
                }
                checkForComodification();
                this.removable = false;
                this.prev.next = this.current.next;
                updateModCount();
                size--;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                checkForComodification();
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                if (this.removable) this.prev = this.current;
                this.current = this.current.next;
                this.removable = true;
                return this.current.data;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return this.current.next != null;
            }

            void checkForComodification() {
                if (modCount != expectedModCount)
                    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }

            void updateModCount() {
                expectedModCount++;
                modCount++;
            }
        };
    }

    private static class Node {

         Node next;
         int data;

         Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

}
```

**SinglyLinkedListTest**

```
package com.singlylinkedlist;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class SinglyLinkedListTest {

    @Test
    public void testEmpty() {
        // we'll leave the while loop because size == 0
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(new int[] {});
        boolean modified = linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertFalse(modified);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingle() {
        // we'll leave the while loop because size == 1
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(new int[] { 1 });
        boolean modified = linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertFalse(modified);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_b_and_c_null() {
        // Initially (b != null && c != null)
        // Then we'll leave the while loop because (b == null && c == null)
        int[] orig = new int[] { 1, 2 };
        int[] reversed = new int[] { 2, 1 };
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(reversed, linkedList.toArray());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_b_not_null_c_null() {
        // Initially (b != null && c != null)
        // Then we'll leave the while loop because (b != null && c == null)
        int[] orig = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] reversed = new int[] { 2, 1, 3 };
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(reversed, linkedList.toArray());
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoopMoreThanOnceEven() {
        int[] orig = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] reversed = new int[] { 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5 };
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(reversed, linkedList.toArray());
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoopMoreThanOnceOdd() {
        int[] orig = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        int[] reversed = new int[] { 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7 };
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(orig);
        linkedList.reversePairs();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(reversed, linkedList.toArray());
    }

    @Test
    public void testToStringEmpty() {
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(null);
        Assert.assertEquals("[]", linkedList.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testToStringNoNext() {
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(1);
        Assert.assertEquals("[1]", linkedList.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testToStringHasNext() {
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(1, 2);
        Assert.assertEquals("[1 -> 2]", linkedList.toString());
    }

    @Test(expected = ConcurrentModificationException.class)
    public void testAddAfterCreatingIterator() {
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = linkedList.iterator();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            linkedList.addFirst(12);
            iterator.next();
        }
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testRemoveTwice() {
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = linkedList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    @Test(expected = NoSuchElementException.class)
    public void testNextAfterIteration() {
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = linkedList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
        }
        iterator.next();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRemove() {
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList = new SinglyLinkedList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = linkedList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int data = iterator.next();
            if (data == 1 || data == 4) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int [] {2, 3}, linkedList.toArray());
    }
}
```

Formally `testLoopMoreThanOnceEven` and `testLoopMoreThanOnceOdd` don't add to code coverage, but I added them because I wanted to make sure the references `a`, `b`, and `c` are reassigned correctly.

Comment: `private int modCount = 0;` to initialize it with `0` is pointless as the default value is already `0` which can be read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). I also recommend adding a full javadoc coverage to it. More can be read [here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html).

Comment: @Emz, this problem is from a job interview. I don't think I would have time to write documentation there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Node a = this.head, b, c;
```

What does this do? It's a rather weird declaration.

```
    while ((b = a.next) != null && (c = b.next) != null) {
        Node d = c.next;
        a.next = c;
        c.next = b;
        b.next = d;
        a = b;
    }
```

Unneeded local store, d can be removed:

```
    while ((b = a.next) != null && (c = b.next) != null) {
        a.next = c;
        b.next = c.next;
        c.next = b;
        a = b;
    }
```

Expanded explanation for those who have a hard time following along:

```
a = 1
a.next = 2
b = 2
b.next = 3
c = 3
c.next = 4

a.next = c

a = 1
a.next = 3
b = 2
b.next = 3
c = 3
c.next = 4

b.next = c.next

a = 1
a.next = 3
b = 2
b.next = 4
c = 3
c.next = 4

c.next = b

a = 1
a.next = 3
b = 2
b.next = 4
c = 3
c.next = 2
```

Now 1 points to 3 points to 2 points to 4. ACBD. Just like the example. Lastly,

```
a = b for next iteration
```

Comment: `d` can't be removed. There is `b.next = d;` in `SinglyLinkedList`

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev You're wrong, see updated answer.